# How do I refresh automatic column widths of a WPF ListView GridView?

Tags: wpf, gridview

How do I force my WPF GridView columns widths to auto adjust to fit their contents?

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of each column to `Double.NaN`. But, first set it to anything but that.

```
foreach (GridViewColumn c in MyGridView.Columns)
{
    c.Width = c.ActualWidth;
    c.Width = Double.NaN;
}
```